# iTextRendered - Russian Characters in PDF

Tags: character-encoding, itext, cyrillic

I'm using iText2.0.8 to generate PDF files.

In brief here's what the code looks like:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fileFullPath);
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(str); //str is HTML fetched from a velocity template
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(fOut);
fOut.close();
```

This works fine. However, when I have Russian characters, they simply show up 'blank' in the PDF. I tried to convert the fetched HTML string to UTF-8 but then the Russian Characters started to show up gibberish.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Any chance you could upgrade to a more recent version of iText? 2.0.8 is older than StackOverflow itself...

Comment: @Alexis I'm curious to know how old 2.0.8 is. When was it released?

Comment: 2.0.8 was released in [January 2008](http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=20&node=208). SO was launched during the summer of that same year.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add font with russian letters, i use in html this:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'Noto Sans';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-display: swap;
      src: url(NotoSans-Regular.ttf);
    }
  body {
    font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
    font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif', 'Noto Sans';
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

and also in code

```
   renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("NotoSans-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("ArialRegular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("microsoftsansserif.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

you need to download the fonts first. You can use site https://sandbox.openhtmltopdf.com/?file=hello-world.htm for research